# How can I display embedded arrays in JSON using $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON file (https://github.com/conde-nast-international/cnid-tech-tests/blob/master/data/article.json) that has five array fields for an article: id, title, body, cover image, and url. But the body array has three embedded array objects (plaintext, pull_quote, and h2) that are not showing up.

I have no idea how to tackle this.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <table id="article_table" class="table table-bordered ">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th>Cover Image</th>
      <th>Url</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
      console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
      var article_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        article_data += '<tr>';
        article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
        article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
        article_data += '<td>'+value.body+'</td>';
        article_data += '<td>'+value.cover+'</td>';
        article_data += '<td>'+value.url+'</td>';
        article_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#article_table').append(article_data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Whole page view:

[image]

Section with embedded array objects that wont display:

[image]

Comment: `JSON.parse` your results.

Comment: @jmargolisvt do you have anymore detail to that answer? I would really appreciate a code example

Comment: It looks parsed already, its just that body is an array of objects and not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since value.body is an array of objects, you will have to iterate through it and display some properties of each object.

```
  $.each(parsedData, function(key, value){
    article_data += '<tr>';
    article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
    article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
    article_data += '<td>';
    $.each(value.body, function (index, el) {
      if (el.type == 'plaintext') {
        // do something special if it's plaintext (?)
      } else if (el.type == 'h2') {
        // put the content in an h2 (?)
      }
      // just display the content
      article_data += el.body;
    });
    article_data += '</td>';
    article_data += '<td>'+value.cover+'</td>';
    article_data += '<td>'+value.url+'</td>';
    article_data += '</tr>';
  });
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! I'm taking your suggestion to add styles according to the if else statement and I'm using the following: plaintext.style.color = red; but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: plaintext isn't a dom element so it doesn't have a style property.  You're concatenating the content into a string, so I would say add something like `article_data += "<span style='color:red'>" + el.body + "</span>";`

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. I currently have if 
(el.type == 'plaintext') {
       article_data += "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold; display:block;'></span>";
              } but the only thing taking effect is the display:block;

Comment: You have to put the content inside the span

Comment: if (el.type == 'plaintext') {
                article_data += "<span 'plaintext' style='color:red; display:block;'></span>";
 
              } doesn't seem to be working either unfortunately

Comment: Look at the second comment where I put el.body inside the span.

Comment: Yes, I've tried all the combinations I can think of but article_data += "<span style='color:red'>" + el.body + "</span>"; doesn't work.

Comment: But don't you find that it is duplicating each array object because that's what I'm getting

Comment: Hmm, nope, I see duplicates in the data but each array element is displayed once.

Comment: I foolishly had another   article_data += el.body; pasted in the script that caused the duplicate! Thank you soooooo very much! Especially for your patience! You've just helped me get a job :)